# How to add tag text on one node as an attribute of another Tag..?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file which has following tags. These are the part of the same XML file which are used number of times. Manual changing would be an tiresome job.

```
<Ids>
 <Id><No>1</No></Id>
 <Id><No>2</No></Id>
 <Id><No>3</No></Id>
 <Id><No>4</No></Id>
</Ids>
```

I want to change this to following format -

```
<Ids>
 <Id n="1"><No>1</No></Id>
 <Id n="2"><No>2</No></Id>
 <Id n="3"><No>3</No></Id>
 <Id n="4"><No>4</No></Id>
</Ids>
```

The above mentioned tags are part of the XML file. The XML file contains another various tags. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="n">
        <xsl:value-of select="No"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<Ids>
  <Id>
    <No>1</No>
  </Id>
  <Id>
    <No>2</No>
  </Id>
  <Id>
    <No>3</No>
  </Id>
  <Id>
    <No>4</No>
  </Id>
</Ids>
```

Output XML:

```
<Ids>
  <Id n="1">
    <No>1</No>
  </Id>
  <Id n="2">
    <No>2</No>
  </Id>
  <Id n="3">
    <No>3</No>
  </Id>
  <Id n="4">
    <No>4</No>
  </Id>
</Ids>
```

Comment: dang it. you beat me by 8 minutes. :P